# Integrating G Analytics to a Node.js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, google-analytics

I am currently stuck with this project : integrating GA to my REST API so I can retrieve metrics and dimensions.
I must highlight that I am running the API on localhost, it may explain why it does not work...?

I tried to integrate GA following different ways :

> ### 1. Using universal-analytics (https://github.com/peaksandpies/universal-analytics/blob/master/AcceptableParams.md)

```
const ua = require('universal-analytics');
require('dotenv').config({path: '../.env'});

// to retrieve the number of connexions to the homepage
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/homepage',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
       ...
       const visitor = ua(process.env.UA_ID);
       visitor.pageview('/bookmarks', 'http://localhost:4000', 'Homepage', (err) => {
          if (err) {
             throw err;
           }
       });

      return reply.view('index');
    }
 });

 // I have pretty much the same thing at the end of a POST endpoint handler
 // to retrieve the number of new data posted

   handler: function (request, reply) {
   ...
   const user = ua(process.env.UA_ID, userId(request.auth.credentials.username));
   user.event('Bookmarks', 'new_bkm_created', payload.title, (err) => {
       if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
    });
 }
```

> ### 2. Creating a trackEvent function (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/integrating-with-analytics)

in google.js

```
const got = require('got');

module.exports = function trackEvent (propertyId, category, action, options) {
  const data = {
      v: '1',   // API version
      tid: propertyId,   // Tracking / Property ID.
      t: 'event',   // Event hit type.
      ec: category,  // Event category.
      ea: action   // Event action.
  };

  if (options) {
      if (options.label) {
        data.el = options.label; // Event label.
      }
      if (options.value) {
        data.ev = options.value; // Event value.
      }
  }

  return got.post('http://www.google-analytics.com/collect', {
      body: data,
      form: true
  });
};
```

in app.js

```
require('dotenv').config({path: '../.env'});
const trackEvent = require('./google');

const postHandler = (request, reply) => {
  ...
  trackEvent(process.env.UA_ID, 'Thing', 'new_thing_created').then(() => {
    return reply(bookmark).code(201);
  }
}
```

> ### 3. Pasting the website tracking code from Admin --> Property ---> Tracking Info (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/)

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=ri[r]=i[r]||function(){  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com, 'analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-XXX-whatev', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I also tried the async version proposed on the link on the third title. The thing is, I do not like this way of doingm I do not understand how to launch events and page views from handlers with ga created in the front end...

Anyway, none of them works... I have no error, but nothing appears in G Analytics.
Just so you know, I used example.com in the default URL as it does not work with a localhost url.

Do you have any lead to help me with this? 
Thank you so much in advance!

-- smgr

Comment: Im curious how you got data to show in the dashboard when running locally. I have debug mode enabled and everything is logging as expected, but no events showing in the dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out one of the three methods worked: the first one with universal-analytics. One needs to be patient to see the first tracked events. I warmly recommend this module though, very developer-friendly ;)